Ошибка Google Play Console: Не удалось подтвердить номер телефона. Попробуйте изменить способ проверки
Не могу подтвердить аккаунт. Уже перепробовал всех операторов Казахстана. Номера Узбекистана и Кыргызстана, Турецкий номер. Всегда одна ошибка "Не удалось подтвердить номер телефона. Попробуйте изменить способ проверки"
Что делать? Подскажите пожалуйста. Срок 1 месяц остался

обращайтесь в техподдержку.
